# Unable to get data from sick laser on Pioneer

Tags: ros, sicklms, pioneer, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using sicktoolbox_wrapper to get laser scans from sicklms200 in diamondback. I am following the procedure described here (http://www.ros.org/wiki/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms)

I get the following message and nothing happens after that.

```
    *** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
    Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The program waits here indefinitely.

No data is being sent on the topic "/scan" as well. (Ran 'rostopic echo /scan'. )
Any help?

**Update**

I have tried using the null modem cable too. The program still waits indefinitely. BTW, I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and Diamondback RC3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9289/unable-to-get-data-from-sick-laser-on-pioneer/) by [Aravindhan K Krishnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/49/aravindhan-k-krishnan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2011-03-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aravindhan K Krishnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/49/aravindhan-k-krishnan/) on 2011-03-06**:
I am using p3dx but the laser turns on only when the sicklms node is launched.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-06**:
Are you using this on a Pioneer (or some other robot that only turns on the laser when a driver attempts to access the laser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was merged officially into the ROS forks of sicktoolbox and sicktoolbox_wrapper about 2 years ago.

If you're running Groovy or Hydro from debs, please set the connect_delay parameter to something like 30 seconds for the Pioneer.
https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper/blob/hydro-devel/ros/sicklms/sicklms.cpp#L207

You DO NOT need to modify the source code, it's already included in the ROS fork of sicktoolbox.
https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox/blob/catkin/c%2B%2B/drivers/lms2xx/sicklms2xx/SickLMS2xx.cc#L110

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Solved**

Debugged the sicktoolbox. The program was hanging at the open() system call for /dev/ttyUSB0 in SickLMS.cc (line number 2319). Added O_NDELAY flag to the second parameter in open() system call and added a sleep(30) system call after open(). Recompiled the sicktoolbox and things started working.

---

Originally posted by [Aravindhan K Krishnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/49/aravindhan-k-krishnan/) with karma: 125 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-11**:
Hi Krishnan, I also couldn't find SickLMS.cc file. I downloaded tarball and install(./configure, make, sudo make install). i also tried sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sicktoolbox. Still no luck. Where n how should i install? thanks in advance

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-10-13**:
@cognitiveRobot, I've added a new answer.  Please look at that.